# Detect text in an image (simple)

Tags: java, computer-vision

I built a simple OCR to detect text. I now need to identify and segment the text from the source image. I used the Canny edge detector to get something like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff75v.png

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post images.
I can't figure out a way to separate the text part. I have read,

1. http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~turkel/imagepapers/text_detection.pdf which is using the Stroke Width Transform
2. ROBUST TEXT DETECTION IN NATURAL IMAGES WITH EDGE-ENHANCED MAXIMALLY STABLE EXTREMAL REGIONS

The algorithms described are probably the best answers but are very difficult to implement in Java. Moreover, in my use cases the text would be prominent much like above. The above algorithms seem like overkill. I would be grateful if anyone can suggest any alternative to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Ofetn the author provide some link to some implementations they have used (although chances are it won;t be in java even if was published). Have you check for any such implementation? I don't think the task you are after is that simple to implement

Comment: I checked. The author did not give a link to an implementation. However, someone had implemented the first using C++. Yes, I am starting to come to the conclusion that this may not be a very easy task.

Comment: I found a link.. http://abstractnonsense.com/portfolio/ocr.html  It's not bad and worked for my test case. Requires a bit of modifications though.

Comment: Yes! I used the Java interfaces for Open CV in the OCR. No restrictions on that.